# Not able to edit the text in WhatsApp EditText using android Accessibility Service from another app

Tags: android, kotlin, accessibility, whatsapp, accessibilityservice

> I am trying to edit the text in the edittext in whatsapp when we send a text along with an image. And then send it by clicking the send button through Android Accessibility Service. But the problem is that the text in the EditText is modified but on clicking the send button the old text is sent along with the image. Any help on this would be appreciated. thanks.

```
class WhatsappAccessibilityService : AccessibilityService() {

override fun onAccessibilityEvent(event: AccessibilityEvent?) {
    val nodeInfo = event?.source ?: return
    val editMessageNodeList =
        nodeInfo.findAccessibilityNodeInfosByViewId("com.whatsapp:id/caption")
   

    if (editMessageNodeList.isEmpty()) {
        return
    }
    for (editMessage in editMessageNodeList) {
        if (editMessage.className.equals("android.widget.EditText")) {
             val message = editMessage.text.toString()
            val suffix: String = "some text"
            if (message.endsWith(suffix)) {
                val bundle = Bundle()
                val newMessage = message.replace(suffix, "")
                bundle.putString(
                    AccessibilityNodeInfoCompat.ACTION_ARGUMENT_SET_TEXT_CHARSEQUENCE,
                    newMessage
                )
                editMessage.performAction(
                    AccessibilityNodeInfoCompat.ACTION_SET_TEXT,
                    bundle
                )
            }
            val sendMessageNodeList = nodeInfo.findAccessibilityNodeInfosByViewId("com.whatsapp:id/send")

            for (node in sendMessageNodeList!!) {
                if (!node.isVisibleToUser) {
                    return
                }
                node.performAction(AccessibilityNodeInfo.ACTION_CLICK)
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(700)
                    performGlobalAction(GLOBAL_ACTION_BACK)
                    Thread.sleep(700)
                    performGlobalAction(GLOBAL_ACTION_BACK)
                } catch (ignored: InterruptedException) {
                    Log.d("TAG", "onAccessibilityEvent: exception $ignored ")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

override fun onInterrupt() {
    Log.d("TAG", "onInterrupt: ")
}
```

}